# PowerBI dynamic column based on slicer selection w/o altering based on row context

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table visual in a PowerBI report and I would like to add a column to it based on the values selected in the slicer for the final date.

So essentially I want to add a column of values that are all the same (max date on slicer), and I do not want this to be changed based on row.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

I tried using the all selected value function and was able to get pretty far - I now have the value of the max date based on the slicer selection, but it changes on each row based on the row context which I do not want. I just want all rows of this new column to show the same date value

Comment: Update your question to include your Measure dax expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CALCULATE(ALLSELECTED(column name),ALLEXCEPT(TableName,Column of slicer))
ALLEXCEPT function will group your data. Works like group by of SQL